# Applescript - Get status of windows ( Visible or in the dock )

Tags: macos, applescript

I need some help for my appleScript.

For all open windows, I want to know which one is hidden (in the dock), which one is visible and which one is focused?

To list windows I use :

```
tell application "System Events"
    set procs to processes
    set windowName to {}
    repeat with proc in procs
        try
            if exists (window 1 of proc) then
                repeat with w in windows of proc
                        copy w's name to the end of windowName
                end repeat
            end if
        end try -- ignore errors
    end repeat
end tell
return windowName
```

I tried focused property:

```
copy w's focused to the end of windowName
```

and selected property:

```
copy w's selected to the end of windowName
```

But this doesn't work!

Thanks for help!

Comment: To find out if a window is in the dock, use the `miniaturized` property. To find out if a window is visible, use the `visible` property. To find out if a window is currently selected (which means it is frontmost), use the `frontmost` property. Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: Thank you. I try `copy w's miniaturized to the end of windowPositions`  but it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.6 (AppleScript 2.1.2) the `description` property of a `window` of an `application process` (in `System Events`' terms) is `"dialog"` if the window is miniaturized (in the Dock), and some other value (such as `"standard window"`, but can be something different depending on the application) if it's not miniaturized.

When an application is **hidden** altogether (using `cmd+H` or the "Hide" command from the application's menu), *all of its windows* will be hidden, regardless of whether they were miniaturized or not, so to find out whether it's hidden, use

```
visible of application process "<ProcessName>"
```

It's `false` when the application is hidden. To un-hide it, set that property to `true`.

To find out which window of an application is currently focused (frontmost/active), use

```
window 1 of application process "<ProcessName>"
```

The list of windows of an application (returned by `windows of application process...`) is ordered by the vertical stack: the frontmost window is first, the one behind it is second, and so on.

Since in OS X only one application is frontmost at a time, and only one window is in the foreground, you'll get at the currently focused window like this:

```
window 1 of (first application process whose frontmost is true)
```

Comment: + I like that window role description of "dialog".

Comment: Can't get the windows at least on mavericks

Comment: @Idan what exactly fails on Mavericks? [This code](http://pastebin.com/1rV3LGRW) works on Mac OS X 10.9.1 (AppleScript 2.6), see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/7pRzAKH.png).

Comment: When using the last command I get: "Can’t get window 1 of application process 1 whose frontmost = true. Invalid index. (-1719)".  

Your script on the link also result with same error. How do you run the script? (I use ASObjC Explorer). By the way, when using Xcode for that I'm getting a different error: "System Events got an error: AppleScriptTest is not allowed assistive access. (error -1719)"

Comment: I ran the script from AppleScript Editor. For the assistive access restriction, you have to explicitly allow the app that runs your AppleScript to control your Mac as of Mavericks. See http://i.imgur.com/d9FjT3u.png

Comment: Ok, It runs with AppleScript editor (so I'll uninstall the other one). What does that means on my app? What should I do for the app to work (Xcode one)?

Comment: Don’t know exactly. Somehow you need to grant that app assistive access.