# Applescript - List all hidden Window in the dock - miniaturized

Tags: macos, applescript

I need some help for my applescript programe.

I want to list all the windows which are open and in the dock, so i tried this :

```
tell application "System Events"
set procs to processes
set windowInDock to {}
repeat with proc in procs
    try
        if exists (window 1 of proc) then
            repeat with w in (every window of proc whose miniaturized is true)
                copy a & w's miniaturized to the end of windowInDock
            end repeat
        end if
    end try -- ignore errors
end repeat
end tell
return windowInDock
```

But it return empty array.

I try to list all windows and get miniaturized parameters (w's miniaturized), but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: **1)** Please do not [duplicate your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155694/applescript-get-status-of-windows-visible-or-in-the-dock) if you are not getting any responses. Instead, you can edit your question so it gets bumped to the top of the *active* tab. **2)** The `exists` property is only used for alias references. **3)** You have a syntax error at the line `copy a & w's miniaturized to the end of windowInDock` (The variable "a" is not defined) so your code shouldn't even run. If you need further assistance, just ask. :)

Comment: Ok thanks! `a` is a separator. I have forget the declaration in my copy/paste. So `a` is declare like that `set a to "@@##@@"`. I need to know if the `w` in my repeat loop is in the dock or not. I don't find any solution, could you help me?

Comment: Take a look at Red_Menace's answer. He seems to be much more fluent in AppleScript than I am, heh (+1 to his answer).

Answer (score 3):

The **exists** command will work for any object, but the window properties from **System Events** are different than the window properties from an application (for example, there is no miniaturized property).  You would have seen the error if you weren't ignoring all of them - wrapping a bunch of code in a try statement without at least logging errors is just asking for it.

What you can do is get a list of applications, then ask *them* to get information about their windows.  Not sure what you were going to do with a list of true values, so in my example I just used the window index:

```
tell application "System Events" to set theNames to name of processes whose background only is false
set windowsInDock to {}
repeat with appName in theNames
    tell application appName to repeat with aWindow in (get windows whose miniaturized is true)
        tell aWindow to try
            get it's properties -- see event log
            set the end of windowsInDock to "window " & it's index & " of application " & quoted form of appName
        on error errmess -- ignore errors
            log errmess
        end try
    end repeat
end repeat

choose from list windowsInDock with prompt "Miniaturized windows:" with empty selection allowed
```

Comment: which system / AppleScript version is this? On my OS X 10.6.8 + AppleScript 2.1.2, a `window` does not have a `miniaturized` or an `index` property.

Comment: I am running Lion, but the script example also runs in Snow Leopard.  It depends, of course, on what is implemented in any given application (for example BBedit windows don't have a miniaturized property), and whether an application is scriptable (Preview).  I just changed the OP's script to move getting the properties away from System Events, but there isn't much error checking done so it looks like getting the windows will fail if some don't have a miniaturized property (I just tested on a few default applications).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that works on all applications, at least on my system.

Try this

```
set windowsInDock to {}
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with this_app in (get processes whose background only is false and windows is not {}) --get applications with 1+ window
        set windowsInDock to windowsInDock & (get windows of this_app whose value of its attribute "AXMinimized" is true)
    end repeat
end tell
return windowsInDock
```

Comment: Note this needs Access for assistive devices to be enabled in System Preferences.

Comment: The above code doesn't run in Mavericks (10.9.2): `System Events got an error: Can’t get every process whose background only = false and every window ≠ {}.`